# How write right route to REST Api Controller with get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have MVC Web Api project. Based on this project I created REST Api controller:

```
   public class ViewConfigFileController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                result = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Config/configData.xml"));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = "Error read XML file!";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I want create manual route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ViewConfigFile",
            url: "ViewConfigFile/Get/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ViewConfigFile", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

After start application I see error: Application doesn't found.
So, How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "{controller}" and "{action}" placeholder in your route config.

Try change your route config to following one.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ViewConfigFile",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ViewConfigFile", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: I edited as you said and call url http://localhost:3855/ViewConfigFile/Get and it's same error.

Comment: @user3231442 As the route defined in your MapRoute method has a default controller and action, therefore, you do not need to specify Get in the url. However, if you have other action methods, you need specify it in your url.